# Display a different header image depending on if the user is mobile or desktop? (Wordpress, "TwentySeventeen")

Tags: css, wordpress, image, responsive

This might be a stupidly dumb question, I'm sorry. I've found plenty on *background* images, but the Wordpress "twentyseventeen" uses "header media", and this is what I'd like to change based on desktop/mobile.

Basically, if mobile they get "header-a.jpg", if desktop "header-b.jpg".

I figure there is a CSS solution, but I can't find it!

Thanks so much for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a default theme the function you want to look at is `get_header_image_tag()`. This function constructs the image tag to be used in the header. At the end of the function you can change what it outputs with the `get_header_image_tag` filter.

You'll need to add some php code. So either create a child theme and add code to your theme's `functions.php` file or create a custom plugin and add the code there. The code should be something like:

```
function custom_header_image_tag( $html, $header, $attr ) {
    if(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Android') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'webOS') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone') ||strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPod') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad') || strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Windows Phone') || wp_is_mobile()){
        $html = "insert custom header image tag here";
    }
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'get_header_image_tag', 'custom_header_image_tag, 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you, is it as easy as just adding this code to my child theme functions.php?
Sorry for the completely stupid question, but what would my input in "insert custom header image tag here" look like specificly?

Comment: @Ads Yes. "insert custom header image tag here"  would be something like `<img src="http://yourdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/filename.jpg"/>` if you uploaded it to the WordPress media library.

Comment: Thank you, however it give me this error:      

Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 619 of file wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.    


syntax error, unexpected ''custom_header_image_tag, 10, ' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)

Comment: Disregard that, it was just a missing '  

THANK YOU works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I have tried below word press code and it is working for me which detect if website load into mobile or desktop,as mentioned in documentation this code consider tablet as mobile.

```
<?php
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) { 
    /*mobile specific stuff*/

    /* header-a.jpg */

}
else{
    /*desktop specific stuff*/


    /* header-b.jpg */

}
?>
```

Check out below link,

[wp is mobile](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile)

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't detecting mobiles that I'm having trouble with. I'd like it to serve up a different header image if mobile is detected. That is the problem, I don't know how to tell it what to do once mobile is detected.